# SignalR generate HttpParseException..??

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR to build simple chat for my site run on Win2003 and IIS6.
Few minutes after this function is deployed, IIS6 automatically disables all of services.

System panic...?
The version I am using is SignalR 0.3. 
Detail logfile for this situation:

*Event code: 3006 
Event message: A parser error has occurred. 
Event time: 5/30/2012 3:22:47 PM 
Event time (UTC): 5/30/2012 8:22:47 AM 
Event ID: fa5b58f6de4f4de2a07d915049cb7e89 
Event sequence: 5 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0*

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/788149765/Root-1-129828397662128750 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: E:\Code\PLW\WebGame\ 
    Machine name: SVCTAG-J7KG62S

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6728 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: Could not create type 'RealTimeChat.MyTest'.
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetType(String typeName)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetTypeToCache(Assembly builtAssembly)
   at System.Web.Compilation.SimpleHandlerBuildProvider.GetGeneratedType(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://haaanjsc.vn/MyTest.ashx 
    Request path: /MyTest.ashx 
    User host address: 210.211.97.164 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 1 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetType(String typeName)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetTypeToCache(Assembly builtAssembly)
   at System.Web.Compilation.SimpleHandlerBuildProvider.GetGeneratedType(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Custom event details:

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Could someone help me please

Answer (score 1):

I don't see SignalR anywhere in that stack trace. Looks like you have another problem.